# Is there a way to enable keyboard shortcuts only when specific file types are opened

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a custom keyboard shortcut `shift + R + enter` which I only want to be enabled when working on `.sql` files. Is it possible to disable the shortcut when any other file type is open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a context clause for language IDs.  For example:

```
{
  "key": "alt+c",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.newComponentFolderAndFiles" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == sql"
}
```

So it is enabled for `sql` files (if that is the language ID) only.  To see the language it click on the language mode in the lower right-hand corner of the vscode window.  You use the version that is in parens, like `SQL (sql)`.  Use the version as it appears in the parens: `sql`.

To enable for multiple filetypes you can do this:

`"when": "editorTextFocus && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(html|css|scss)"`

See [conditional operators for when clauses](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_conditional-operators).

Comment: Just to add, finding the right language code is a pita, see this answer for getting the code for your language: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73912165/how-do-i-see-all-current-file-associations/73912222#73912222. Also, probably goes without saying, but not conditions are also super useful here: `editorLangId != html`.