# How do I see all current file associations?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code is aware of many file types, but I cannot find any information on where to see all file types it currently understands.

I want to see which file type is associated with which language.

If I view the file associations it's totally blank:

[image]

I want to add a new association. I want to associate `*.inc` as a restructured text file. But figuring this out is a guess right now, what is the "code" for the restructured text language?

Is it `rst`:

[image]

Or is it "restructured text"? Or another value. My VS Code currently associates `*.rst` files with restructured text, but I cannot see that configuration anywhere.

## Edit

Per the accepted answer I found the language code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I've found for a global association is simply to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type "change language mode")` with a file of the type you're associating open.

In the first selections will be the option "Configure File Association for 'x' " (whatever file type - see image attached). Selecting this gives you the option to choose the language and will then make the filetype association permanent.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4ncj.png)

This may have changed (probably did) since the original question and accepted answer (and I don't know when it changed) but it's so much easier than the manual editing steps in the accepted and some of the other answers, and totally avoids having to muss with IDs that may not be obvious.

**Answer 2**

In VScode, you can add persistent file associations for language highlighting to your `settings.json` file like this:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
  "some_setting": custom_value,
  ...

  "files.associations": {
    "*.thor": "ruby",
    "*.jsx": "javascript",
    "Jenkinsfile*": "groovy"
  }
}
```

You can use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` (or View -> Command Palette from the menu) and then type settings JSON. Choose Preferences: Open Settings (JSON) to open your settings.json.

To find the proper language ID, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (or View -> Command Palette from the menu) and then type Change Language Mode. You can see the language ID in the list, e.g. type docker to find the language ID for Docker files (dockerfile). In the first entry in the example above, .thor is the file ending, ruby is the language ID.

Comment: But this is my problem, doing that through the UI works, but where does that config go? It's not in my `.vscode` folder and it's not in my user `vscode-settings.json` file.

Comment: If the new answer helps